# Reading large CSV with multi-threading is not using all cores

Tags: python, multithreading, csv

I found some of code on stackoverflow and when I run this script it works but does not use all threads (I have 4 core CPU). Can you help me how to improve this script to use all threads and increase read and write speed from and to file?

```
import re
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
from random import randint

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time start =", current_time)
pattern = re.compile('some pattern')

filename = 'out.csv'

def process_line(l):
    sleep(randint(0, 3))

def get_next_line():
    with open("in.csv", 'r') as f, open(filename, 'w') as csvout:
        csvreader = csv.reader(f)
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvout)
        csvwriter.writerow(["aa", "bb"])
        for rec in csvreader:
            matches = pattern.findall(rec[1])
            if matches:
                for match in matches:
                    csvwriter.writerow([rec[0], match])

f = get_next_line()
t = Pool(processes=4)
if f is None:
    t.close()
        t.join()
else:
    for i in f:
        t.map(process_line, (i,))
        t.close()
        t.join()
now = datetime.now()
current_time_end = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time End =", current_time_end)
```

Comment: You can't.  This is linear process that does read, filter, write, and the results must be published in order.  There's no practical way to parallelize this.  `get_next_line()` will run the whole file to completion, then the job is finished.  Of course, you can speed it up by removing the pointless multiprocessing stuff that does nothing but sleep.  The job is done when `get_next_line` returns.

Comment: Besides what @Tim said, threads in Python mostly don't run concurrently and never use more than one CPU core. It's possible to use `multiprocessing` to run separate processes concurrently, but using them would not be applicable to the kind of processing you want to do.